# Ripping a DVD to watch on iPod touch

Tags: itunes, dvd, ipod-touch, codec, ripping

I have a DVD that I'd like to watch on my iPod touch.  Can I use normal PC ripping software or is there something special I need to do to get iTunes to sync it to my iPod?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a good article on [LifeHacker](http://lifehacker.com/291306/rip-dvds-to-friendlier-formats-with-handbrakex) on how to do that with [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/)

> The free, cross-platform HandBrake
>   makes ripping DVDs to a bevy of
>   useful, playable file formats a cinch,
>   with support for iPods, PSPs, Apple
>   TVs, PS3s, and pretty much any other
>   format your device requires. It's
>   fast, free, and takes the difficulty
>   out of both ripping and transcoding.

Answer (score 4):

I use [AnyDVD](http://www.slysoft.com/en/anydvd.html) to remove the copy-protection and Handbrake to rip it to an iPhone compatible size and format.  Then I drag it into iTunes to put the resulting video on my iPhone.

It should work exactly the same for your iPod Touch.